# Writing assumed-size array causes "upper bound shall not be omitted..."

Tags: fortran

I am writing code to add on a closed-source Finite-Element Framework that forces me (due to relying on some old F77 style approaches) in one place to rely on assumed-size arrays.

**Is it possible to write an assumed-size array to the standard output, whatever its size may be?**

This is not working:

```
module fun

implicit none

contains

subroutine writer(a)
integer, dimension(*), intent(in) :: a
write(*,*) a
end subroutine writer

end module fun


program test
use fun
implicit none

integer, dimension(2) :: a

a(1) = 1
a(2) = 2

call writer(a)

end program test
```

With the Intel Fortran compiler throwing

```
error #6364: The upper bound shall not be omitted in the last dimension of a reference to an assumed size array.
```

Comment: if you are using modules your "old code" is no longer f77. If you are using a module here but not in the "real" problem you ought to revise the question.

Comment: I updated the introduction accordingly. My own code is F2003, but I write mockups for some internal F77-style procedures of the closed-source FE code to run my code in a debugger. Ref. to the comments to Vladimir's post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler does not know how large an assumed-size array is. It has only the address of the first element. You are responsible to tell how large it is.

```
 write(*,*) a(1:n)
```

Equivalently you can use an explicit-size array

```
integer, intent(in) :: a(n)
```

and then you can do

```
write(*,*) a
```

Comment: I unfortunately can do neither, since the subroutine `writer` above is part of a commercial closed-source FE Framework which I am developing a subroutine for. I am writing a replica of that closed-source routine to replace it while testing - in there I want to place the write statement. To make my actual code compatible with both, the original and the replica `writer` subroutine, I must use assumed-size arrays.

Comment: In that case use the first, `write(*,*) a(1:n)`. it IS for assumed-size arrays. Please read carefully again.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: `n` is not known at compile time as `a` will have different sizes for different calls of `writer`. I guess it's not possible then.

Comment: That is the point!!! In `write(*,*) a(1:n)` the `n` is a variable. You are responsible to supply the actual array size at runtime.

Comment: Ok. That's not going to happen in a convenient way. Thanks for the clarification. (Btw, I just found out the commercial tool infers the array sizes from the format string used to print the array elements nicely... I'd rather use a preprocessor and conditionally defined procedure pointers then to point to a sane implementation using assumed-size arrays in my debugging usecase...)

Answer (score 2):

An assumed-size array may not occur as a whole array reference when that reference requires the shape of the array.  As an output item in a write statement that is one such disallowed case.

So, in that sense the answer is: no, it is not possible to have the write statement as you have it.

From an assumed-size array, array sections and array elements may appear:

```
write (*,*) a(1:2)
write (*,*) a(1), a(2)
write (*,*) (a(i), i=1,2)
```

leading simply to how to get the value `2` into the subroutine; at other times it may be `7` required.  Let's call it `n`.

Naturally, changing the subroutine is tempting:

```
subroutine writer (a,n)
  integer n
  integer a(n)      ! or still a(*)
end subroutine
```

or even

```
subroutine writer (a)
  integer a(:)
end subroutine
```

One often hasn't a choice, alas, in particular when associating a procedure with a dummy procedure with a specific interface .  However, `n` can get into the subroutine through any of several other ways: as a module or host entity, or through a common block (avoid this one if possible).  These methods do not require modifying the interface of the procedure.  For example:

```
subroutine writer(a)
  use aux_params, only : n
  integer, dimension(*), intent(in) :: a
  write(*,*) a(1:n)
end subroutine writer
```

or we could have `n` as an entity in the module `fun` and have it accesible in `writer` through host association.  In either case, setting this `n`'s value in the main program before `writer` is executed will be necessary.

Comment: Great answer too!